# How to get a function's MethodInfo from within the function?

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose there is a function `GetEmployees`:

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(Dictionary<int, Department> depts, bool isFullTime)
{
    // How do I get the MethodInfo of this "GetEmployees" function by writing code here?
}
```

The reason I need to get the **MethodInfo** inside this function is that I need to know

- The function name ("GetEmployees")
- The number of parameters ("2")
- The parameter names ("depts" and "isFullTime")
- The parameter types ("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[int, Department]&" and "System.Boolean")
- The return type

Thanks!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit to your question becuase the edit completely changed the scope of it to the point of being a different question. If you want to ask a question about how to get the parameter values, that is a new question.

Comment: If you're looking to add logging to all of your methods, you could use something like PostSharp (or another tool that allows for [aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)) to inject logging code for you. See [here](https://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.CustomLogging/) for an example with PostSharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you want this:

```
MethodInfo myMethod = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
```

And you can get the reflected parameters like so:

```
ParameterInfo[] parameters = myMethod.GetParameters();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to ask: once I have this MethodInfo, how do I get the values of the parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by "the values"? Do you mean the values that are passed to `GetEmployees` when it's called?

Comment: When this "GetEmployees" method is called by a client, the client passes in certain values to to the parameters. Calling MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() only gets the static MethodInfo, which says "This method has a Boolean parameter called "isFullTime", but how does my code get the "false" that had been passed in via this "isFullTime" parameter by the client?

Comment: Every time a client calls this method, my code is supposed to be executed. It shall not only find out the MethodInfo and ParameterInfo, but also the parameter's values.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that.